# Does an Android .aar built with Gradle contain dependencies?

Tags: android, aar

Not sure why I can't find any answers on this. If I convert my library project into an .aar using Gradle in Android Studio, does it retain all the dependencies of that module?

I'm asking because I'm trying to use a Gradle generated .aar locally, but it looks like only some of the original dependencies have been packaged. Namely, it complains that I'm missing 'OkHttp', but if I add it to the main project I get duplicate class errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually a library does not directly contain its dependencies. This does not matter whether it is an aar or a jar. Instead, the library declares its dependencies in the Gradle build file and they are resolved when someone uses the library.